# CSS hover based on caret position (contenteditable div)?

Tags: javascript, css, contenteditable

I have something like this:

```
<div class="content" contenteditable="true">
  <p>Some text</p>
  <p>Some other text</p>
</div>
```

Right now I can do `.content p:hover` (e.g. color: red) to manipulate the CSS. But that only works with the cursor.

How can I do it so I can manipulate CSS based on the caret's position (specific paragraph)?

Comment: Can you show the markup of the caret?

Comment: can you describe a bit that final effect you want to achieve ? Highlighting up to a specific (*hovered*) letter ? or a specific paragraph ?

Comment: how can you place a caret into the paragraph? is it about a Wysiwig editor?

Comment: Im unsure what you want - do you want the latter you are hovering on to be red? If you are looking for text-selection within the paragraph to be styled, you can use the `::selection` pseudo-element. Otherwise, if its the former you can't do it as individual letters are not elements.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/p375c3ys/